# Why does this Python code return a generator object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

Here's the part of the code that confuses me (explained below):

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end

intervals = [Node(1, 2), Node(3, 4), Node(5, 6)]

starts = sorted(i.start for i in intervals)
ends = sorted(i.end for i in intervals)
```

Why does `(i.start for i in intervals)` return a generator object and why does removing the parentheses like so `i.start for i in intervals` returns an invalid syntax error?

Comment: What's your question? `(i.start for i in intervals)` is the [syntax for a gen-exp](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) hence it returns a generator and `i.start for i in intervals` is not a valid syntax.

Comment: What, in your code, is a the generator? The value of `starts` or `ends`? Or `(i.start for i in intervals)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(x for x in y)` is a shorthand way to create a Python generator.
 If you want to iterate through the list, use

```
for x in y:
    # do stuff
```

The parentheses let Python parse the expression as one token, which lets it know you are trying to create a generator. Without the parentheses, Python initially sees the `i.start`, so it's expecting an expression. The `for` keyword throws it off though since that start a new statement. The parentheses group it all together into one token when the interpreter reads it, so Python is able to recognize it as the generator syntax.

Comment: `sorted()` returns a list itself.

Comment: You're right,  I was thinking about `reversed` for some reason.